# How do I create a generic Rust struct with a chrono time zone?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

Disclaimer: I am new to Rust (previous experience is Python, TypeScript, and Go, in that order), and it is entirely possible that I am missing something really obvious.

I am trying to build a Rust clock interface. My basic goal here is that I have a small clock struct that reports the actual time, and a stub version that will report a faked version for testing. Note that these are historical tests rather than unit tests: my goal is to replay historical data. I think part of the problem may also be that I do not understand `chrono` well enough. It is clearly a great library, but I am having trouble with the type vs. instance relationships in `chrono` and `chrono_tz`.

Anyway, this is what I have:

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, TimeZone, Utc};

/// A trait representing the internal clock for timekeeping requirements.
/// Note that for some testing environments, clocks may be stubs.
pub trait Clock<Tz: TimeZone> {
  fn now() -> DateTime<Tz>;
}
```

My ultimate goal is to have other structs have a `dyn Clock` in a particular time zone. That clock may be the system clock (with appropriate time zone transformation) or it might be a stub of some kind.

This is my attempt at a system clock shim, and where everything is going horribly wrong:

```rust
/// A clock that reliably reports system time in the requested time zone.
struct SystemClock<Tz: TimeZone> {
  time_zone: std::marker::PhantomData<*const Tz>,
}
impl<Tz: TimeZone> Clock<Tz> for SystemClock<Tz> {
  /// Return the current time.
  fn now() -> DateTime<Tz> {
    Utc::now().with_timezone(&Tz)
  }
}
```

The key problem is `Utc::now().with_timezone(&Tz)`. The compiler wants a *value*, not a *type*. Fair enough, except `chrono` and `chrono_tz` do not seem to have time zone values. I have been looking all over for the right thing to put here and nothing seems to be the right answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the time zone *type* is not sufficient to implement `now()` as specified. Most time zones aren't implemented as separate types, `Utc` is actually special in that regard (as is `Local`). Normal time zones are implemented as *values* of more general time zone types, such as `FixedOffset` or `chrono_tz::Tz`. Those types store the time zone offset at run-time, so valid `FixedOffset`s include `FixedOffset::east(1)` (CET), `FixedOffset::west(5)` (EST), or even `FixedOffset::east(0)` (GMT, UTC). This is why `DateTime::with_timezone()` requires a concrete time zone value, not just its type.

The simplest fix to accommodate this is to modify `now()` to accept a time zone value:

```
pub trait Clock<Tz: TimeZone> {
    fn now(tz: Tz) -> DateTime<Tz>;
}

struct SystemClock<Tz: TimeZone> {
    time_zone: std::marker::PhantomData<*const Tz>,
}

impl<Tz: TimeZone> Clock<Tz> for SystemClock<Tz> {
    fn now(tz: Tz) -> DateTime<Tz> {
        Utc::now().with_timezone(&tz)
    }
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
fn main() {
    // now in Utc
    println!("{:?}", SystemClock::now(Utc));
    // now in GMT+1
    println!("{:?}", SystemClock::now(FixedOffset::east(1)));
    // now in Copenhagen time
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        SystemClock::now("Europe/Copenhagen".parse::<chrono_tz::Tz>().unwrap())
    );
}
```

Note in particular the second and the last example, where the time zones are chosen at run-time, and are clearly not captured by the time zone type.

If you find it redundant to specify the time zone value in trait methods such as `now()`, you could give the methods access to `self` and keep the time zone value in a field in `SystemClock` (which would also nicely eliminate the `PhantomData`):

```
pub trait Clock<Tz: TimeZone> {
    fn now(&self) -> DateTime<Tz>;
}

struct SystemClock<Tz: TimeZone> {
    time_zone: Tz,
}

impl SystemClock<Utc> {
    fn new_utc() -> SystemClock<Utc> {
        SystemClock { time_zone: Utc }
    }
}

impl<Tz: TimeZone> SystemClock<Tz> {
    fn new_with_time_zone(tz: Tz) -> SystemClock<Tz> {
        SystemClock { time_zone: tz }
    }
}

impl<Tz: TimeZone> Clock<Tz> for SystemClock<Tz> {
    fn now(&self) -> DateTime<Tz> {
        Utc::now().with_timezone(&self.time_zone)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", SystemClock::new_utc().now());
    println!("{:?}", SystemClock::new_with_time_zone(FixedOffset::east(1)).now());
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1c28b318de91ca97855b963ed4c38f3)

For time zones where the offset is known at compile-time, such as `Utc` and `Local`, the time zone field will take up no space, and `SystemClock` will be zero-sized, like in your original design. For time zones where the offset is chosen at run-time, `SystemClock` will store that information in the struct.

Finally, with the advent of const generics, one could imagine a variant of `FixedOffset` that stores the offset at compile time as const generic. Such types are offered by the [`chrono-simpletz`](https://crates.io/crates/chrono-simpletz) crate, which you can use to create the kind of `Clock` trait you wanted initially. Since its types are fully specified at compile-time, they implement `Default`, so you can trivially obtain the time zone value with `Tz::default()`. The result (sadly again requiring `PhantomData`) might look like this:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

use chrono::{DateTime, TimeZone, Utc};
use chrono_simpletz::{UtcZst, known_timezones::UtcP1};

type UtcP0 = UtcZst<0, 0>;  // chrono_simpletz doesn't provide this

pub trait Clock<Tz: TimeZone + Default> {
    fn now() -> DateTime<Tz>;
}

struct SystemClock<Tz: TimeZone> {
    time_zone: PhantomData<fn() -> Tz>,
}

impl<Tz: TimeZone + Default> Clock<Tz> for SystemClock<Tz> {
    fn now() -> DateTime<Tz> {
        Utc::now().with_timezone(&Tz::default())
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", SystemClock::<UtcP0>::now());
    println!("{:?}", SystemClock::<UtcP1>::now());
}
```

In case it's not obvious which option to choose for production, I recommend the second one, the one with the playground link.

Comment: Not OP but really clear answer, thanks. I take ages to get my head around datetimes whenever I need to use them so this is getting bookmarked.

Comment: Thank you for this incredibly detailed answer. I will try to implement tonight and officially accept once I have done so. Thank you!